# Bootstrap three column layout collapsing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin

I am trying to create a Bootstrap three unequal column layout with col-md-3, col-md-6, col-md-3. Everything works fine, however when I try to add margins to the columns, it collapses them. I was wondering how to prevent that, I'm assuming it has something to do with the Bootstrap column property or the column width. I appreciate any help I get, thanks!

```css
#mid {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#favorite {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#free {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3" id="favorite">
      <h2 class="text-center">Favorite</h2>

      <div class="ins">
        <h5>Blah</h5>
        <div>
          <img src="" height="40" width="40"> Blah
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="" height="40" width="40"> Blah
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="teach">
        <h5>Blah</h5>
        <div>
          <img src="" height="40" width="40"> Blah
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="" height="40" width="40"> Blah
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6" id="mid">
      <h1 class="text-center">Upcoming</h1>
      <div class="lesson-info" id- "1">
        <img src="" height="40" width="40"> Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn blue_button">Start</button>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn white_button">Cancel</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3" id="free">
        <h3 class="text-center">Get free</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add padding rather than margin . Margin creates space outer to you div so the bootstrap css to your becomes messy and will not align as you wanted to your code

```css
#favorite {
  background-color: red;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `padding` instead of `margins`.

Bootstrap uses the column classes to generate a width percentage, so adding margins to the columns will render over 100% width and break your layout.

You might need to adjust your markup to get the same look as adding margins. For example, if you want to add a background color to the columns but have a space between them, then you can add a wrapper div inside the column, apply the color to the wrapper element and add padding to the column.